# Show selector options always down

Tags: html, angular, html-select

Regardless of the number of items,is it possible to open the selector options always down?
For example I have the following selector

html

```
<ul>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
  <li>An item</li>
</ul>
<div>
  <select>
      <option value="">Options</option>
      <option value="{{x.id}}" *ngFor="let x of data">{{x.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

ts

```
 data:any=[{
    id:1,name:'a'
  }];
  ngOnInit(){
    for(let i=1;i<20;i++){
      this.data.push({
        id:i,
        name:'a'
      })
    }
  }
```

it shows:

[image: IMG1]

how show always down?:

[image: IMG2]

Comment: it is a default behavior of html element. You would have to develop your own dropdown

Comment: maybe with popper.js flex-diirection (maybe)